# Can we change HTML tag in VueJS dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dynamic

I have code like this:

```
<TabItem name="Font Family" :selected="true">
   <typography-font />
</TabItem>
<TabItem name="Typescale">
   <typescale />
</TabItem>
<TabItem name="Usage">
   <typography-usage />
</TabItem> .... and more <TabItem>
```

Is it possible to replace the HTML tag dynamically if I want to make it loop using v-for like this?

```
<tabItem v-for="directlink in links"> 
  <{{ directLink }}/> 
<tabItem>
```

Comment: Hi. Could you rephrase the question a bit? It's not clear what you are asking (sorry)

Comment: @Dejan.S so I want to change the tag inside TabItem dynamically using computed or something else for showing respective page using v-for value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dynamic component provided by Vue `<component :is="componentName" />`.

Looking at your current setup, you could use an array of objects to render the items you want.

Example:

```
// template
<TabItem v-for="(directlink, index) in links" :key="index" :name="directlink.name">
  <component :is="directlink.component"/>
</TabItem>

// script
data() {
  return {
    links: [
      {
        name: 'Font Family',
        component: 'typography-font'
      },
      {
        name: 'Typescale',
        component: 'typescale'
      },
      // ... etc. You could also load this data from a .json file.
    ]
  }
}
```

Related reading:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components